# How to execute a class method from another class with the method passed a parameter in Python

Tags: python, oop, methods, callback

I'm a beginner in learning python..
I'm looking for help in solving an OOP problem

My main program has something simplified like below:

```
class abc(Frame):
     def _init_(self,  master)
           Frame.__init__(self)     
           self.B1 = Mybutton(self.master, self.cmd)
     def cmd(self):
           print("hello world")
```

In the main program, I import Mybutton class in another file, which is simplified as below:

```
class Mybutton():
     def _init_(self, parent, command):
           self.command = command

     def A_ramdom_fcn(self): 
           ...
           self.command()  ------------------>> here I want to execute the command
                                                                       in class abc, not in class Mybutton.
```

How to execute a method from another class that is passed as an instance method, you may ask why not just execute it in class abc, but I have event attached to button press, it needs to do a roundabout to achieve this..

Comment: That was a typo here, in the main program it's correct..

Answer (score 0):

First, fix the typos: missing `:` in `abc`'s init method, and it should be `__init__` (with two underscores) for both classes.

---

It seems like you've gotten yourself turned around. You've set things up correctly using composition: an `abc` has a `Mybutton`, and it looks like you correctly pass the function to `Mybutton` so that it can execute it. In fact, your code will work as written if you do, for example

```
a = abc(master)  # no context for what master is, but I assume you have it
a.B1.A_ramdom_fcn()
```

With the way you've set things up, you don't want to import and make instances of `Mybutton` in your main program (what `abc` would they belong to?). You want to import and make instances of `abc`. You then access their internal `Mybutton` like I've shown in the example above. This works because when you pass `self.cmd` to the `Mybutton` constructor while inside the `abc` constructor, it's already a bound method of the `abc` you're constructing.

---

As an addendum, it looks like you might be having an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) with regards to why you need such a roundabout method. Is there any reason why you can't simply pass `abc.cmd` to the button press handler?

Comment: Hi Josh. Thanks for the reply. It’s indeed a xy problem...  i meant to ask how to access my class method from another class, in this case accessing  cmd() and print “hello world” from Mybutton class

The reason i want to do that is to create customized button widget in Tk, so that it looks nicer and i can just say B1=Mybutton(root, x,y, mycommand) and it calls the command in class abc, but since its passed to Mybutton, i have to callback...

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, what you are trying is possible, you can capture the object method into variable and call it later (python 3):

```
class Window:

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_button = Mybutton(self.cmd)

    def cmd(self):
        print("hello world")


class Mybutton:

    def __init__(self, command):
        self.command = command

    def a_ramdom_fcn(self):
        self.command.__call__()


win = Window()
win.my_button.a_ramdom_fcn()
```

I assume you are trying to make the generic `Button` class which doesn't know what to do when it's clicked and you want to put the actual logic into your `Window` class.

That makes sense, but it would be even better to extract the logic into the third, `Command` class. This allows us to limit the `Window` responsibility and also avoid the trick with method-as-variable (the `command` we pass to the button object is just another object):

```
class HelloWorldCommand:

    def execute(self):
        print("Hello world")


class Window:

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_button = Mybutton(
            HelloWorldCommand()
        )

class Mybutton:

    def __init__(self, command):
        self.command = command

    def a_ramdom_fcn(self):
        self.command.execute()


win = Window()
win.my_button.a_ramdom_fcn()
```